# how ro run python func 10 a.m. every day

Tags: python, time, slack

Func should run at 10 a.m with one arg, 11 another, but I am not sure what to use. Are there library for that sake?
That is my function:

```
import os
from slackclient import SlackClient

BOT_NAME = "bot"
SLACK_API_TOKEN = "token"
BOT_ID = "id"

sc = SlackClient(SLACK_API_TOKEN)


def send_message(text):
    sc.api_call(
        "chat.postMessage",
        channel="#madchickens",
        text=text
    )
send_message("here func work")
```

Comment: Why do you want to use Python to take over an OS's responsibility? I suppose one way is to have a lookup table with the message and the corresponding time, then continually check the clock... but do consider something like `cron` if you're on Linux.

Comment: User, who need this app is not able to use something like cron. It should be one button app.

Comment: I suppose so, but you should be handling that on behalf of the user. The one-button click should take care of this as well :) Good luck, though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User @icedwater is right: scheduling something to run at a specific interval, time of day, day of week, day of month, etc. is a job best handled with a tried-and-tested *nix tool like [crontab](http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html).

Given that answer, however, you could modify your script to use the `sleep(n)` function in the `time` module, to allow your bot/script to do something every n seconds. Here's an example that would run an action every 24 hours:

```
import time

SECONDS_PER_HOUR = 3600
HOURS_PER_DAY = 24

while True:
    print("glorp")
    time.sleep(SECONDS_PER_HOUR*HOURS_PER_DAY)
```

You could also use sleep to run a function every hour, and check what the hour number is, performing conditional actions based on the hour number (the hour number here is 24-hour format, so 0 for midnight, 12 for noon, 23 for 11 PM, etc.):

```
import time
import datetime

while True:
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    if(now.hour==8):
        print("bleep")
    if(now.hour==10):
        print("bloop")
    if(now.hour==23):
        print("blarp")
    time.sleep(3600)
```

These are simple examples that could be easily replicated with a cron job, but you can see how this could be built out to implement much more complicated and interesting timing logic...